# Одинаковая разность чисел в двух массивах

Tags: математика

Даны два целых числа: m, n. И есть два массива длинной 20, первый содержит случайные числа от 0 до m, а второй случайные числа от 0 до n. У нас нет информации о числах в этих массивах. Нужно вернуть True если можно сказать с уверенностью 100%, что можно взять по паре чисел из каждого массива, чтобы у этих пар была одинаковая разность

Я не знаю как вообще подступиться к этой задаче, буду рад если вы сможете помочь!)

Comment: Что значит «равна любой разнице в аналогичном массиве»?

Comment: Да, я понял что непонятно объяснил, сейчас все исправил)

Comment: Хм, в первой версии условия были неповторяющиется числа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На 100% не уверен, но... :)

У вас, кстати. не сказано "до m/n включительно" или нет, так что использую "включительно".

С уверенностью 100%, не изучая массивы, можно сказать только в некоторых случаях. Например, если `m` и `n` меньше 19, то в каждом массиве обязательно будет пара одинаковых чисел, а значит, и в одном, и во втором есть пара, разность для которой равна 0. Уже при `n=m=19` можем получить числа в одном массиве от 0 до 19, а во втором — одни нули, например...
И хотя такая вероятность весьма мала, но тем не менее она не нулевая. Так что навскидку — 100% можно сказать только при `m<19 && n < 19`.

Подвис на ситуации, когда одно значение меньше 19, а второе **немного** больше. Вот тут и есть те проценты, о которых я написал *"на 100% не уверен"*. Пока не могу ни доказать, что все будет хорошо, ни привести контрпример...

Кстати, экспериментально получается примерно вот так — по осям шкала логарифмическая, 2 соответствует 100, 4 — 10000...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, в первой версии условия были неповторяющиется числа.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Отвечал на то, что прочитал. P.S. тем паче что, посмотрел — вопрос исправлен самим автором...